# jQuery blur on hover effect problems

Tags: jquery, css, hover, blur

i have a problem with jQuery again, I hope someone can help me out.

please view the Portfolio section here http://matoweb.com (there should be two items)

I'm redesigning my portfolio website and I want to list last 6 portfolio items with a blur hover effect. I managed to get this working with one image (the second one that was actually the first post) but now I added another test portfolio item and have two problems:

- i only get the blurred image of the first post (second image), the image of the second post doesn't get it's own blurred version image
- the second problem is that when I hover over one image it triggers animation for the second one, too

here is the code for these effects, but you may view it in action on website:

```
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(".img_portfolio").pixastic("blurfast", {amount:1});
        });

        $(function() {
            $(".prva_stran_portfolio_single").mouseenter(function () {
                $(".normal_image").fadeOut("fast");
            }).mouseleave (function () {
                $(".normal_image").fadeIn("fast");
            });
        });
        $(function() {
        $(".roll").css("opacity","0");

        $(".roll").hover(function () {

        $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.9
        }, "fast");
        },

        function () {

        $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
        }, "fast");
        });
        });
```

any help would be really appretiatied guys.

How could I add some sort of ID to the images, so that they don't all blur when hovering over only one of them?

Comment: are you trying to blur? or are you just simply trying to use an opacity effect?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just a hover, I would use an each(function) to keep them all separate.  They should not be in different functions, really...keeps things cleaner and easier to debug this way.

```
$(".prva_stran_portfolio_single").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        Run everything that happens on a hover (mouse in) here.
    },{
        Run everything that happens on a hover (mouse out) here.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an ID, you should be able to call `.find("normal_image")` which will search all descendant elements. Conversely, you could use `.closest()` to search all ancestor elements for the closest matching element.

I'm not sure why pixastic is not creating a blurred canvas for both images, my suggestion would be to try using a `.each(function() {  pixastic(blur)  })` with the selector.

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't seem to work... I guess I'll have to forget about the blur on hover effect..

Answer (score 0):

This is a clean and simple way to accomplish what you want.

```
var blurredImages = $( '.blur-me' );

blurredImages.on( "mouseenter", function () {
  $( this ).addClass( "blurred" );
})

blurredImages.on( "mouseleave", function () {
  $( this ).removeClass( "blurred" );
})
```

Also, I recommend using CSS3 transition instead of jquery animate for transition timing. It's much faster.  I included it in the fiddle.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mE3b/